# How to deal with the missing satellite data in interpolation procedure

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

The satellite data I have downloaded contains the spatial distribution information for certain species.

Some places which covered by cloud when the satellite overpass are regarded as NaN value.

But when I want to interpolate the satellite data (2-D array) into  another shape(For example, coarser the resolution). The NaN value troubled me a lot.

Due to the existing of the NaN value, the scipy.interpolate function can't return a finite value.

Here is my code, the data file I have uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQX25mTzJIMW9TeG8/view?usp=sharing):

```
 lon,lat = np.linespace(75.12,135.12,241), np.linespace(18.12, 55.12, 149)
 data = pd.read_csv("./CH2O-NO2/test.csv").values.reshape(lat.shape[0],lon.shape[1])
```

I can plot the 2-d distribution of `data` with Basemap package.

[image]

#### Interpolation

```
from scipy import interpolate
#### Coarse lat-lon pairs

lon_2,lat_2 = np.linespace(75.12,135.12,100), np.linespace(18.12, 55.12, 50)  

hfunc =  interpolate.interp2d(lon, lat, data)

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(lon_2,lat_2)
data_coarser = np.zeros(xx.shape[0]*xx.shape[1])
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(xx,yy)):
    data_coarser[i]=hfunc(x,y)
```

The code runs slow, and the data_coarser has many NaN value.

#### My attempt

Working with missing data is one tricky question in my daily work.  For 2-d array-like dataset, is there any method to replace NaN value with some of its neighborhood grid?

Comment: scipy.interpolate2d cannot handle NaN values for interpolation. It asks for a value at this position, but does not receive any. So your actual question will be: how do I fill up those missing values? By default, the interpolate2d algorithm will interpolate between all 9 pixel neighbors. You could first identify the position of all NaNs and replace them by their nearest neighbor. But no matter how you solve it, you will always "manipulate" your data and influence the result by your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Can't post comments still.

As [offeltoffel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3728958/offeltoffel) have mentioned, any filling will bring bias to the data.
You might be interested in image inpainting techniques in case when NaN areas are not so large. I was able to find some implementation in `OpenCV`, but there are a lot more different ideas (in theory): http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

I was able to find some Wolfram Mathematica functions for inpainting: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inpaint.html .
You can also google for "image inpainting". Query will yield a lot of scientific articles on that matter. If you're confident, you can try few of them.

Another approach that might bring some success: replace all the NaN with zeros (or mean, or something else), rescale it, and then replaces zeros ( ... ) with the NaN again.

Hope this can help